# dual boot issue : ubuntu has stopped working after installing win 7

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, boot-repair

I've had Windows 7 (64bit) and Ubuntu 12.10 installed and running fine for a couple of weeks ,due some reason I needed to reinstall windows 7 but since reinstalling windows 7 I'm completely unable to boot Ubuntu.

After going through some posts,  I tried to fix it using Boot-repair but instead of getting the problem solved the following message was shown:

> "64bits detected. Please use this software in a 64bits session. (Please use Ubuntu-Secure-Remix-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/ubuntu-secured) which contains a 64bits-compatible version of this software.) This will enable this feature."

How can I fix this??

Answer (score 0):

You can download Ubuntu-Secure-Remix-64bit here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntu-secured/files/